# Trouble while logging to docker hub registry from bootdocker in windows

Tags: docker, boot2docker, dockerhub, docker-registry

I have installed boot2docker for windows,then I have created an image of my application and trying to push it to my docker hub registry public repo.While running the command "docker push" its asking me to login and then prompting me for username.When I enter my username it does not do anything.Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did `boot2docker ssh` and then typed`docker login` to login to docker hub registry and then was able to push my image